# Can't get to the Internet from VLAN on switch

Tags: switch, vlan, firewall, networking, sonicwall

I'm trying to setup a network lab to learn more about networking.

Equipment:

- 2 procurve switches.
- 1 Sonicwall firewall TZ300

The final outline:

- traffic from Vlan 10 on switch 1(port1) goes to Sonicwall (X0) to the Internet
- traffic from Vlan 20 on switch 2 (port 1) goes to switch 1(port 5) then goes to Sonicwall (X0) to the Internet

Current config of switch 1:

```
hostname "ProCurve Switch 2510G-48"
snmp-server community "public" Unrestricted
vlan 1
name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
untagged 1-9,16-19,26-48
ip address dhcp-bootp
no untagged 10-15,20-25
exit
vlan 10
name "customer"
untagged 10-15
ip address 10.240.10.1 255.255.255.0
tagged 1
exit
```

Current config of Sonicwall is:

[image]
[image]

At the moment my conputer on Vlan doesn't have Internet connection. However, it can get an IP from the DHCP function of the Sonicwall. I'm stuck on this for the pass week. I have no idea how to go about the second part of the final outline. If you have any idea, please point me to the resources. Thank you guys.

**----Edit with solution:**
Thank you everyone for your help.

Part 1 of outline:
I removed the routing policies in the firewall.
keep Vlan 10 interface IP on sonicwall 10.240.10.1
Set Vlan 10 IP on switch 1 to 10.240.10.2

Part 2 of outline:
Create Vlan 20 on Lan interface on Sonicwall
Create vlan 20 on switch 2 with IP address: 10.240.10.3
Connect Switch 1 (port 3) to Switch 2 (port 1)
On switch 1 console:

```
 Switch01(config)# trunk 3 Trk1 LACP
 Switch01(config)# vlan 10
 Switch01(vlan-10)# tagged Trk1
 Switch01(config)# write mem
```

On Switch 2 console:

```
 Switch01(config)# trunk 1 Trk1 LACP
 Switch01(config)# vlan 10
 Switch01(vlan-10)# tagged Trk1
 Switch01(config)# write mem
```

Comment: `trunk` is for bonding multiple physical interfaces together. It has nothing to do with vlan tagging. Unless you are running parallel links between switches, and between the switch and firewall, there's no need to setup trunks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't use the same IP address 10.240.10.1 for both Switch 1 and firewall.
2. VLAN 20 is missing from Switch 1 altogether, so there's no connectivity from it to the firewall.

Comment: Thank you @Ron-Trunk. I changed Vlan 10 IP on the switch to 10.240.10.2, and remove all the customs rules on Sonicwall. I have internet connection on Vlan 10 now. However, I notice that I can go to 192.168.168.168 from Vlan 10. Is there anyway to make it go to 10.240.10.1 strictly to access the firewall?

Comment: We can't see your firewall policies, you need to add them to your question. Not sure about the Sonicwall but some firewalls default to permit everything when no single policy is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your host is on VLAN 10, but your firewall is on VLAN 1.  To route between VLANs, you need a router.  If your Procurve switches are layer-3 capable, you can enable routing between the VLNAs.

If not, either put the Sonicwall in vlan 10

```
vlan 10
untagged 1
```

Or

put your host in VLAN 1

Comment: 2510 are layer 2 only.